# slider ui breaks in chromium based browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, user-interface

i've been trying to build a slider with a specific design. The slider works fine on other browsers but google chrome and brave it shows weird patches whenever next a point on the slider line is clicked.

[image: slider image for more explaination]

There is no new element created and nothing shows up on inspecting the tab with dev tools. here is the link to the slider for better perspective about the issue. https://thirsty-sinoussi-ce3553.netlify.app/

edit: github link for whole code-> https://github.com/rawaldeep/timelinegraph

Comment: Hi Rawal, if Chrome then Edge too as from 2020 onwards they use the same code base. Probably some misssing vendor prefix. How about posting a [reprex]?

Comment: Hey Rene, you can find the whole code at this link: https://github.com/rawaldeep/timelinegraph